# Define value as variable

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

How can I define value of variable as variable name?
For example I define `x` as `newname`

```
(define x 'newname)
```

then I want to define new variable with name of value of `x`.

I want something like

```
(define x 'asd)
```

and if I call `newname` I get `'asd`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Both Scheme and Common Lisps original binding way did this but you tend to find yourself debugging for hours because you forgot to quote the symbols. The result is that `set` advanced to `define` in Scheme and `setq` in CL while the previous version became deprecated and totally removed in Schemes case.

I'm pretty sure you got a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) so if you could explain what you are trying to do with such a feature there must be a way to solve your problems without them.